# HPE 2910al Switch - Schedule a job

Tags: switch, hp-procurve, hpe

According to the documentation found at the below URL there is a function on the 2910al to run a scheduled job, called "Job Scheduler"

https://techhub.hpe.com/eginfolib/networking/docs/switches/common/15-18/5998-8158_bog/content/index.html

As per the documentation the syntax of the command is:

```
HP_Switch# (config) job <name> at
job <Name> at [HH:]MM [on [MM/]DD][config-save]<Command>
job <Name> at <Event> [config-save] <Command>
no job <Name>
```

However when I try to run a test command, for example:

```
job test at 11:30 "write mem"
```

I get the following error:

Invalid input: job

Also if I run "Show ?", the command job is not in the list.

Does anyone know why this might be and if there is another way to schedule a job on a 2910al?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running an ancient firmware version that's your problem. I dimly seem to remember that `job` came with 15.x and wasn't in 14.x yet.

The latest (and likely final) firmware release is W.15.14.0018 and can be downloaded here: https://h10145.www1.hpe.com/downloads/SoftwareReleases.aspx?ProductNumber=J9145A

Also, your console snapshot looks a bit weird. You need to enter `configure` context first and can then enter configuration commands:

```
conf
job test at 11:30 "write mem"
```

[EDIT] On checking with a spare 2910al from storage, it seems it's lacking the `job` command after all. I thought I remembered using it but apparently that was only on our 2530 switches (16.x firmware).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm running W.15.14.0018 and I'm entering configure terminal mode. It seems the command is not there?

Comment: Hmm - I'll fetch a 2910al from storage and check that, hang on.

Comment: [...] See my edit above - doesn't seem to be in 15.x, sorry.